# Refreshing External data connection to Sharepoint library in Excel file automatically

Tags: c#, excel-interop, sharepoint-online

I have a requirement where i have to refresh the external data in an excel file on SharePoint online at certain times. 
Getting authenticated and getting the file with csom is not a problem. 
The problem is that when using com to refresh the external data source com is not authenticcated to do so.
There does not seem to be a function in Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel where refreshing the data can take a fedauth cookie. Or should i write the fedauth coockie somewhere on disk where Excel can find it ?

Answer (score 0):

Think i solved it. 
If anyone ever needs it i used the interop

```
[DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool InternetSetCookieEx(string lpszUrlName, string lpszCookieName, string lpszCookieData, uint dwFlags, IntPtr dwReserved);
```

to set the fedauth cookie obtained by code and Excel seems to be able to find it